# Typescript array null-safe

Tags: typescript

Assume I have such code:

```
function concat(a: string, b: string):string {
    return a + b;
}

function firstPlusWorld(items: string[]):string {
    return concat(items[0], ' World');
}

console.log(firstPlusWorld([]));
```

In this case typescript won't argue that the first argument passed to `concat` is not a string.

In functional land there is `Maybe` type and `head` function has type signature

```
head :: List a -> Maybe a
```

Is there any way to make typescript handle such cases?

Comment: Non-nullable types are a very good concept, but they're only integrated in a limited number of languages thus far. JavaScript, and its derivative project TypeScript, are not among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to resort to good/old `if` tests. Typescript does not add anything to javascript in that respect.

There are tentatives to bring Monads to Javascript (and Typescript by extension) such as this one: https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land (https://github.com/fantasyland for implementations)

I am still frustrated at this stage and if anyone finds a good library, I will be glad to jump on it and write typescript definition files for it if need be.

On the data structures and immutability front, things are a bit better with [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) but it would be great to wrap the structures in Monads so operations on them could be better chained.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `string` as the TypeScript type can also accept `null`:

```
function concat(a: string, b: string):string {
    return a + b;
}

concat(null, null);
```

Does this answer your question?